# SQL case sensitive query with BETWEEN

Tags: sql, sql-server

On SQLServer 2012, why does the query:

```
SELECT 
   Firstname 
FROM 
   dbo.CWIndividualGivers 
WHERE 
   FirstName BETWEEN 'r' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND 'rzzz' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Return values like 'Ruth' and 'Renee'?

I would expect the names with capital letters in the first position to be excluded.  How does BETWEEN work in case sensitive collation?

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: Put the COLLATE on all three operands.

Comment: I did try adding the collate to all three, unfortunately, it didn't work

Comment: So what happens if you avoid the use of the old deceiver and just write `FirstName > 'r' AND FirstName < 's'`?

Comment: unfortunately, no go on the > and < approach

Comment: You used collate after the FirstName and it didn't work? i can't imagine why... but in this case you could add this to your where clause `AND FirstName = lower(FirstName)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
Select LEFT(Firstname, 100)
FROM dbo.CWIndividualGivers
WHERE FirstName like 'r%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

**NOTE:** 100 is just a number, you can replace this with however long the longest name in your dataset is.

Comment: Yes, if I were only searching for the first letter I would have used this approach, however, I'm trying to allow someone to search in a range of first letters (e.g. a to c, including all the c's)